# iOS - Can an app running in the background send touch / gesture events to another app in the foreground?

Tags: ios, background-process, gestures, touch-event

I have been asked to develop an app that will record and later "play back" touches and gestures onto another app running in the foreground.

From my experience and knowledge, this is not possible unless both apps are setup to send/receive data between them through notifications or other methods. Also, it would be a huge risk for apps and their data to be exposed to anybody.

I am 99% sure this is not possible, but was just curious if anyone else has come across something similar (or documentation that specifically states this is forbidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope not possible, no way no how, dont even try.

Expanded answer, if this runs on a jailbroken phone.......

Yes.... but good luck,

check Saurik's Veency code for this sort of functionality, it would have to be refactored signifcantly but basically it allows for virtualization of taps.

https://github.com/iceNuts/TouchTest

http://gitweb.saurik.com/veency.git

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Just curious if I was mistaken. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access another application in your iPhone ,you can set the url scheme parameter and so on.You can add callback in your url，then you can return back your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible with facebook's idb:
https://github.com/facebook/idb/

As it stated: 
Remote Automation. idb has a “companion” that runs on macOS and a python client and cli that runs anywhere. This enables scenarios such as a “Device Lab” within a Data Center or fanning out commands to large numbers of iOS Simulators.

As facebook stop support on WebDriverAgent, it's the best option we have right now