# Record iOS / Android application user tests

Tags: android, ios, user-testing

I would like to know if there is any way to record gestures (more generally touch and keyboard events) performed by a user over an arbitrary application.

Idea is to launch an app to test, then record input events. The app to be tested could potentially be any app from the app store / google play.

I have seen that question but would like to confirm the answer (and also for Android): [iOS - Can an app running in the background send touch / gesture events to another app in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400835/ios-can-an-app-running-in-the-background-send-touch-gesture-events-to-anothe)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it for more information, Please have look of the [**Gorilla logic`s monkey talk**](http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk) SKD for both platform.

Now i will come to iOS, Apple provides framework for UI testing using automation so for that you can check [**Usingthe Automation Instrument**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) official link from apple.

you can find good tutorial at [**iOS automated tests with UIAutomation**](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation)

Comment: All these solutions are more for UI automation, not analysing how real users are using an application. Furthermore, most of them imply connecting the device to a computer with a set of tools installed.

Comment: have you check Gorilla logic ? for that computer connection is not req.

Comment: It requires an IDE + connection to computer from what I have seen. http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/command-recording/connect

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, for security reasons. This would make writing keylisteners, and other 'hacker' apps possible.

Comment: I know the security implications. However, there are some legitimate use cases for such tools. Thanks anyway.